# Splitting string using RegEx

Tags: python, regex, parsing, split

**I'm trying to use RegEx Tokenize to split the following string data:**

`"• General     The general responsibilities of the role are XYZ • Physical Demands     The Physical Demands of this role are XYZ • Education Requirements     The education requirements for this role are • Bachelor's Degree • Appropriate Certification • Experience     5 years of experience is required"`

**I want to reach this as the final stage:**

| A header |
| --- |
| • General The general responsibilities of the role are XYZ |
| • Physical Demands The Physical Demands of this role are XYZ |
| • Education Requirements The education requirements for this role are • Bachelor's Degree • Appropriate Certification |
| • Experience 5 years of experience is required" |

I've had success with grouping it, and parsing it, but it's not as dynamic as I'd like.

There is a pattern I want to split by: ***• *words* multiple spaces*** i.e.  **•.*?\s{3,}**

NOTE: one of the categories uses bullet points within it (Education Requirements). This is the part that I find most problematic.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Perhaps RegEx Tokenize isn't the most dynamic either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use:

```
•\s+[^\s•].*?\s{3,}.*?(?=•[^•\n]*?\s{3}|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `•\s+` Match • and 1+ whitespace chars
- `[^\s•].*?` Match a non whitespace char other than • and then match any character, as few as possible
- `\s{3,}` Match 3 or more whitespace chars
- `.*?` Match any character, as few as possible
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert that to the right is

  - `•[^•\n]*?\s{3}` Match `•`, then as few as possible chars other than • or a newline followed by 3 whitespace chars
  - `|` Or
  - `$` End of string
- `)` Close the lookahead

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/KFg9Oq/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IvEd07)

```
import re

s = "• General     The general responsibilities of the role are XYZ • Physical Demands     The Physical Demands of this role are XYZ • Education Requirements     The education requirements for this role are • Bachelor's Degree • Appropriate Certification • Experience     5 years of experience is required"
pattern = r"•\s+[^\s•].*?\s{3,}.*?(?=•[^•\n]*?\s{3}|$)"
result = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(result)
```

Output

```
[
'• General     The general responsibilities of the role are XYZ ',
'• Physical Demands     The Physical Demands of this role are XYZ ',
"• Education Requirements     The education requirements for this role are • Bachelor's Degree • Appropriate Certification ",
'• Experience     5 years of experience is required'
]
```

**Note** that using `\s` can also match a newline. If you don't want to match newlines, you can use `[^\S\n]` instead.

Comment: I love the approach, and thank you for going the extra mile to explain your logic . Unfortunately I don't think your Output quite matches my expected output above. If you look at your last bullet point, you will see \n ' • Experience     5 years ... ' .. I was hoping for that to be the last section. 

I still can use your logic as a base, seperate out the last row and parse it. This is still a dynamic approach! I'm just wondering if it can all be completed in one step though?

Comment: Amazing stuff. Last month you taught me about optional non-capture groups. Now I can learn the Positive Lookaheads. I appreciate it a tonne!

Comment: I guess we can take out [^\s•] as .*? will do that part? i.e. •\s+.*?\s{3,}.*?(?=•[^•]*?\s{3}|$) @The fourth bird

Comment: @BenjaminStringer Yes, if that works for your data as well, then you could do that. I added it to make sure to match at least a single non whitespace character other than • and the `.*?` can also match 0 characters.